# criteria for left outer join in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables named as 'A' and 'B'. Table 'B' primary key is mapped as foreign key in 'A' table as 'b_id'(column name). In table 'A' the primary key of 'B'(b_id) may be null. i.e. In the 'B' table record doesn't exist. Table 'B' will have column 'del_flag'

Now i need to select **all rows** from 'A' table(including which are having 'b_id' as null).  if **b_id** is not null in table 'A' then i need to check the **'del_flag'** of table 'B' is '0'(zero or not). **i.e** if 'B' record exist i need to display only the records whose 'del_flag' is 0 .

How to write the **criteria** for the above condition.

I am trying with the following first two conditions. Based on my requirement it should work.

```
   criteria.createAlias("b", "m");  -----> (1)
   criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("b"),Restrictions.eq("m.del_flag", "0"))); --->(2)

   //criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("b"));  ----->(3)
```

**Let's come to the proble what i am facing.**

The problem is with the '**creatAlias**'.   I changed my requirement to select only which are having **'b_id'** as **null**.  I executed only **(1) (3)**  conditions (**2 is commented**). I got **empty record**.

After struggling some time, i **commented** the condition **(1)** also . Now i **got** the result set.

if i execute **(1)** and **(3)** i am getting not getting result set. only **(3)** is giving the result set.

I am thinking that   **this might be the reason** for my  **actual requirement** .

Comment: I had been assuming that you have a entity A with a field, 
     private B b;
and entity B with a field,
     private Object delFlag;

Comment: yeah. your assumption is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
session.createCriteria(A.class)
            .createAlias("b", "bClass")
            .setFetchMode("bClass", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("bClass"),
                    Restrictions.eq("bClass.delFlag", 0)));
```

Comment: then what about the rows of table 'A' which are having 'b_id' as null.

Comment: Did you try the above? It should match that condition.

Comment: yeah. the above will gives the rows which are having 'b_id' as not null